# How to search for a folder in directory using perl

Tags: perl

I am new to perl script. I want to search for a each folder named "abc" in directory "pqr" and write path of each "abc" folder to a separate file (n.txt where n is an integer) in the form filename = pathOfABC. Can anyone please give me some hint on this?

Comment: Is Google/Bing working today? Have you tried to give it a shot? Show us the progress so far.

Comment: what do you mean "each abc folder" ?  look into the `readdir` function.

Comment: I can tell you the path of that folder without running a program. It's `pqr/abc`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the task involves recursion, you can employ a module like [`File::Find`](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aFind).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;

my @files;

sub wanted {
    if ( -d && $_ eq 'abc' ) {
        push @files, $File::Find::name;
    }
}

find \&wanted, 'pqr';

my $ctr = 1;
for (@files) {
    open my $fh, '>', "$ctr.txt" or die "Error opening file";
    print $fh $_;
    $ctr++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`Path::Class::Rule`](https://metacpan.org/module/Path%3a%3aClass%3a%3aRule) module makes searches like this very concise.

The code would look like this.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Path::Class::Rule;

my $rule = Path::Class::Rule->new->dir->name('abc');

print "$_\n" foreach $rule->all('pqr');
```